# How to translate "by the way" and "anyway": linker expressions

Tags: перевод, словоупотребление

I find it difficult to understand how to translate some English expressions used to "link" sentences in order to make your language more fluent.
For example:

"Ok let's meet tomorrow at 9... **By the way**, you can ask your friends if they want to join us"

Or

"blablabla(long speech going on)...**anyway**, let's cut this boring conversation short — I want to show you my new car" --> change of topic

or

"I forgot to buy the cake. It doesn't do much good, **anyway**"

How can each of these sentences be expressed in Russian? Please provide me with some *formal/informal* variants (if they exist).

Answer (score 3):

**By the way** usually corresponds to **кстати**.

> **By the way**, you can ask your friends if they want to join us --> **Кстати**, ты можешь пригласить своих друзей

**Anyway** can be different depending on context.

> **Anyway**, let's cut this boring conversation --> **Ладно**, давай оставим этот скучный разговор (or maybe simply "*Ладно*, хватит об этом")

But

> It doesn't do much good, **anyway** --> А, **всё равно** это ни к чему (or maybe *Всё равно* бе́з толку)

Answer (score 2):

The usual translation of "*by the way*" is "**кстати**" or "**к слову**" or "**между прочим**".

The usual phrase used where an English speaker would use "*anyway*" is "**как бы то ни было**" or any other introductory phrase or word, like, "**ну**", "**ну что же**", etc.

> "Ok let's meet tomorrow at 9... **By the way**, you can ask your friends if they want to join us"

would be
*"Ладно, давайте встретимся завтра в 9...  **Кстати**, вы можете спросить своих друзей, не хотят ли они к нам присоединиться.*

And the sentence

> "**Anyway**, let's cut this boring conversaion, I want to show you my new car."

would be
*"**Ну,** давайте прекратим эту пустую болтовню, я хочу вам свою новую "тачку" показать."*

Comment: I'd add "в любом случае" as a translation for "anyway"

Comment: And I'd add "как бы то ни было" to anyway. That's a bit long, of course, but I use it sometimes.

Comment: None of your "anyways" work for the "let's cut this boring conversation" one. It should be either **в общем** or **короче**.

Comment: In case of "let's cut this boring conversation" you can also use "ладно". It's closer to "OK" by meaning, but it's used in such cases rather frequently.

Answer (score 2):

by the way = между прочим, кстати

anyway = в любом случае

Answer (score -3):

"By the way" - Впрочем, к слову сказать(or говоря), между прочим, кстати,

Literally : по дороге, по пути

Colloquial : кстати сказать.

And, indeed, you can use "по пути" or "попутно"(it's better) whatever you need, this usage implies the usual level of figurative, metaphoric logic for Russian.

Я объяснял эту тему и попутно рычал как медведь.

---

"Anyway" : во всяком случае, в любом случае, как бы то ни было, каким бы то ни было образом, как бы то ни было, как-нибудь, всё равно как, так или иначе...

and любым путем :>